# Storing value in django models without using Model forms

Tags: django, django-models

I am having very complex models in my project, that I cannot display easily on HTML page using modelForms.

So I want to to use normal forms instead and store the values in Models.is it possible?

Comment: ....[yes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form).

Comment: Anything's possible if you write enough code. What, exactly, are you asking?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. You simply create your own form by inheriting forms.Form.
Then get the form input from request in your views and create your object.

In short what you are asking is possible.

Here is the official documentation for forms: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/